# How to compare three (or n) values and output the minimum value using nodes

Tags: node-editor, mathematics

I want to compare three values (RGB) and then pass the minimum (or maximum) along the node chain. For instance an input of (100,50,255) would output 50. The math node only allows you to pass along one value for comparison.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shader nodes?  SeparateXYZ (or SeparateRGB, it doesn't matter, they do the same thing) and then run serial minimum operations:

[image]

Dividing by 255, because your numbers suggest you're interpreting color as values in 0,255 when Blender interprets colors as 0,1.

Serial maximum operations will work the same way.

If you want to, you can node group all of that stuff to make a MinimumVec node group, for easy reuse.

Comment: Duh. Thanks so much. Learning more each day.